# Finding number pattern

Tags: exponential-function, estimation

I have a program which I originally thought was linear, meaning that if I had twice the data, the program would take twice as long to process.

I was wrong, and it seems to be somewhat exponential.

Here are my results

```
300 words (1 folder) = .9 sec
600 words (2 fld) = 2.1 sec
900 words (3 fld) = 3.8 sec
1200 words (4 fld) = 6.6 sec
1500 words (5 fld) = 9.7 sec
3000 words (10 fld) = 37.5 sec
```

I have all my words in a folder, and I tested the program with multiple copies of the same folder. Keep in mind this is a real world test, so the numbers may not be exactly as they "should be."

I would like to find an algorithm to be able to estimate how long the program will take based on how many words the user inputs.

My estimation for 30,000 words (`100 fld`) was `1407 sec` which I arrived at from `dividing` my time from 3,000 words (`37.5 sec`) with my time from 300 words (`.9 sec`) which was `41.7`.

I then multiplied `41.7` with `37.5`, and divided the result by `.9` which gave me `1407`.

Perhaps I was right with this estimation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your data$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 300 & 0.9 \\
 600 & 2.1 \\
 900 & 3.8 \\
 1200 & 6.6 \\
 1500 & 9.7 \\
 3000 & 37.5
\end{array}
\right)$$

as you noticed from a plot, they are nonlinear but look either to be quadratic or exponential.

Assuming that time is $0$ for $0$ words, we can fit the model $$t=a w + b w^2$$ (linear regression) or $$t=a(e^{bx}-1)$$ (nonlinear regression)

For the first case, we get $$t=3.900822 \times 10^{-6} w^2+0.000781384 w$$ to which corresponds an $R^2=0.999859$.

For the second case, we get $$t=4.49706 \left(e^{0.000745006 w}-1\right)$$ to which corresponds an $R^2=0.999553$.

Both fits are excellent for the covered range. But the problem now is to extrapolate for values of $w$ much larger than the upper value of $3000$. For $w=30000$, the first model would give $t=3534.18$ while the second would give $t=2.28817\times 10^{10}$ (!!) which does not seem to be very realistic.

So, stay with the first model.

**Edit**

Simpler than the quadratic model would be $$t=8.79388 \times 10^{-6} w^{1.90657}$$ to which corresponds an $R^2=0.999737$. For $w=30000$, this last   model would give $t=3020.87$.

Comment: Wow, that is very close to what I actually got in my program which was `t = 3242` (but I'm running this test again for accuracy). If it's not too complex, how did you go from (correct me if I'm wrong) `t = aw^2` , to `t = 8.79388 X 10^-6w^1.90657`

Comment: Good to know ! It was so close to a quadratic that I tried $t=aw^b$ independently.